# Users Seeing Blank White Screen on some Android versions

Tags: android, xml, apk

I had a developer work with me on creating this app, Adventures In Ministry, for Android.  Recently, it appears that the song section is not working on most android devices.  I do not code very much with Android, and was wondering if someone could check out this apk file and see what the issue may be?  The app parses an xml of all the songs which are just pdfs.  Clicking them opens up a web view of the link of the pdf.

[APK of the app](http://www.316apps.com/AIMExample/aim.apk.zip)

Comment: For some reason the link automatically shows this for apk files.  I have compressed in a zip and am uploading it now.  Should be up in a few minutes to 316apps.com/AIMExample/aim.apk.zip

Comment: Can we really debug an apk?

Comment: I've heard that an apk is essentially just a zip.  This was an app that was developed for me, but developer no longer available to fix this issue.

Comment: It's not really trustworthily to link to a apk you could also include an exploide which dameges my device. Please add the relevent code to your question. (Even if it could be simple to reverse engineer your app).

Comment: All I have is the apk which was submitted to Google Play and not the actual code

Comment: In case of a published app it is better to link to the Play Store (aka Android Market). If I understood you right and you have no access to the sourcecode what do you want? You could not fix it anyway.

Comment: Link is https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.threesixteenapps.aim.  If I knew what problem was it could possibly be something simple to get in and fix.

Comment: The source files(activities and other java files) are compiled to `classes.dex`. Retrieving `classes,dex` is as easy as opening the apk with a unzip/unrar tool. You could peek into(and extract from) a dex file using a disassembler. But next, you have class files(compiled java code) which you need to decompile. And then, you can start the debug process.